# Installing ws for node on RaspberryPi

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, ws, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm encountering the following issue with installing ws for javascript node (v. 15.8.0)
on a raspberrypi zero 2 w.

```
julius@pi:~ $ sudo npm i ws
TypeError: Class extends value #<Object> is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/read-entry.js:90:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js:27:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:163
      throw new Error('call config.load() before reading values')
      ^

Error: call config.load() before reading values
    at Config.get (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:163:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:171:32)
    at process.emit (node:events:378:20)
    at process._fatalException (node:internal/process/execution:163:25)
julius@pi:~ $
```

Thanks a lot for your Help

Julius

Comment: Can you reproduce the bug on something else? Is the Pi a factor here or just coincidental?

Comment: Pi got just unboxed today.

Comment: Not what I'm asking. **Can you reproduce this on another computer?**

Comment: I'll try to do the same on an other linux machine

Comment: It helps to narrow this down to A) Hardware, B) Node version, C) dependency version, D) OS. Right now it's far from clear what the scope is, but that'll help a lot.

Comment: For what it's worth I had no trouble installing `ws` on macOS but with Node 20.8. You're using a fairly old Node version, one not even listed on the [support window page](https://github.com/nodejs/Release). It could be that version is just not supported by current versions of `ws`. Odd numbered versions are also more short-lived, they're not LTS. 18 and 20 are going to be supported through 2025 and 2026.

Comment: Using this version of node, because I had prior issues with the installation of ws, saying it cant finde the installation dir of node.js with the newer version.

Comment: Tried on Ubuntu with same node version: same error.
Then tried with Node 20.9.0:  working. 
Tried with same Node on RasPi: Now working.
Very sorry to waste your time, but with the first install it didnt work, saying "cant find Node dir".

Comment: Not a waste of time if you got it working.